# Which mountain is the highest in Aftica

Tags: word-choice

Do native speakers use the word order of the second sentence?

1. "Which is the highest mountain in Africa?"

2."Which mountain is the highest in Aftica?"

Comment: The most common way of asking this, I think is _**What** is the highest mountain in Africa?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the blue, or in a quiz, we would generally use 1.

If 1 has already been asked, then, in the course of a discussion, we might use 2 for variety, emphasizing *highest* if we had already been discussing African mountains; emphasizing *Africa*, if we'd been discussing the highest mountains elsewhere, or perhaps, emphasizing *mountain*, if we'd been discussing the heights of *other* things in Africa, or *is*, if there had been some argument about which mountain really *was* the highest.

(We might even emphasize *in* if we've been discussing the heights of mountains off the mainland, or *which* if we have already forgotten which mountain we were just told was the highest!)

Answer (score 1):

A brief answer is that both sentences are correct and are said by native English speakers, but the first one is far more common and natural sounding. They do, of course, mean exactly the same.